# Android different swipe directions using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have an app, where I use ViewPager to swipe. So far I can only swipe RightToLeft. And what I want is to swipe RightToLeft, swipe down and swipe up. I hav 3 fragments, but it only swipes RightToLeft.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomViewPager vpPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    vpPager.getCurrentItem();

    // Attach the page change listener inside the activity
    vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // Code goes here
        }

        // Called when the scroll state changes:
        // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // Code goes here
        }
    });

}

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 1:
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 2:
                return ThirdFragment.newInstance(2);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Here is the ViewPager Code

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

/**
 * @return {@code false} since a vertical view pager can never be scrolled horizontally
 */
@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return true;
}

/**
 * @return {@code true} iff a normal view pager would support horizontal scrolling at this time
 */
@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically(int direction) {
    return super.canScrollHorizontally(direction);
}

private void init() {
    // Make page transit vertical
    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
    // Get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right (the ripple)
    setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}




private static final class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1);
            view.setTranslationX(0);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Anyone who can help me with adding 2 more swioe directions?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager) library.

Comment: @azizbekain, is there not an easier and more simple way to do this?